# React js - Ant Design switch changing although Ok button is not pressed

Tags: reactjs, antd

Hello I am having a problem here in my switch and by the way I am using Ant Design switch. What I want to happen is when I click the switch a popup should appear first asking if the user wants to switch on or off and when the user click ok the switch should change.

Here is my code

```
import Modal from 'antd/es/modal';
import Switch from 'antd/es/switch
const { confirm } = Modal;

handleOk = () => {
  confirm ({ 
    title: Are you sure you want to switch on ?
    okText: 'Yes',
    cancelText: 'No',
    onOk() {
      console.log('The switch is now on')
  }
}
```

And here is my code for switch

```
<Switch onClick={this.handleOk} />
```

The output is when I click the switch the popup or modal appear and when I click the Ok button it logs in the console "The switch is now on". My only problem is the switch is moving although I didnt click the Ok button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it as a *controlled component* to control weather it must be switched or not.

```
export function MyComponent = () => {

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (!checked) {
      confirm ({ 
        title: Are you sure you want to switch on ?
        okText: 'Yes',
        cancelText: 'No',
        onOk() {
          setChecked(true)
      }})
    } else {
      setChecked(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Switch onClick={handleClick} checked={checked}/>
  )
}
```